# Using a template with multiple input files

Tags: templates

I regularly write assessments of students and would like to separate the design from the content part. So what I imagine is having as input

- one template file
- either multiple files (one per student) containing the data (name, test result, multiple lines of text,...)
- or a single file (for all students; one student per line) for instance as a csv

The output should be either one pdf (one page per student) or multiple pdf files (one file per student).

Is there a package (or packages) that can achieve this?

I saw that there is a [solution using csvsimple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594189/how-to-import-text-files-to-populate-the-right-places-in-latex-template) that goes into this direction but I don't see how I could extend it to use multiple files and also I don't like the curly braces in that solution.

Comment: TeX can only output one pdf per run.  The easiest way to get multiple pdfs is to have some other program create the student file and then call latexmk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [datatool package](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{students.csv}
Name, Question, Answer
John, Question1, Answer1
Bill, Question2, Answer2
Robert, Question3, Answer3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
  
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{data}{students.csv}
\DTLforeach{data}
{\student=Name,\question=Question,\answer=Answer}
{\newpage \student \par \question. \par \answer.}
\end{document}
```

as well as [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
  
\begin{document}
\csvreader{students.csv}{}
{\csvcoli \par \csvcolii. \csvcoliii. \clearpage}
\end{document}
```